# Socketio behavior is not unique

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Last few days I spend creating chat ( I try to learn socketio ) and finally I create that I can see room and emit that room on my front end and everything work fine.
Until I connect with my mobile phone ( or in new browser ) then if I press for example "room1" its open in all device...

Somehow its sync with all device and this is my code so far

```js
io.on('connection', async socket => {

    console.log('Coonected to chat');

    socket.on('createRoom', async (data) => {
        const room = data.room;
        const username = data.username;
        const roomToLeave = Array.from(socket.rooms)[1];
        socket.leave(roomToLeave)
        socket.join(room);

        io.to(room).emit('userIsConnected', username);

        const roomExist = await Chat.findOne({ roomTitle: room }).select('chat roomTitle');

        if (roomExist) {
            const chat = roomExist.chat;
            io.to(room).emit('historyOfRoom', chat);
        } else {
            await Chat.create({
                username: username,
                roomTitle: room,
                seen: true
            });
            const findAllRoom = await Chat.find().where('isActive').equals(true).select('-_id roomTitle');        
            io.emit('list-of-rooms', findAllRoom);
        }
    });
}
```